# How to fix "runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)" in leetcode?

Tags: vector, merge

I am doing leetcode problem 88(Merge Sorted Array).It is showing "Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9" when i click on run button.Could anyone please figure out my mistake?

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void merge(vector<int> &nums1, int m, vector<int> &nums2, int n) {
        vector<int> ans(m+n);
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        while(i<m&&j<n){
            if(nums1[i]>nums2[j]){
                ans[k++]=nums2[j++];
            }
            else{
                ans[k++]=nums1[i++];
            }
        }
        while(i<n){
            ans[k++]=nums1[i++];
        }
        while(j<m){
            ans[k++]=nums2[j++];
        }
        nums1=ans;
    }
};
```